# Using path.join on NodeJS on Windows to create URL

Tags: windows, node.js, url, path

I have two dynamic pieces of a URL that I'm trying to join together to make a full URL.  Since I don't know the exact strings I'll be joining, I want to use a path-joining library to avoid string-joining errors like `"http://www.mysite.com/friends//12334.html"`, which has an extra slash, etc.

I am working on a Windows 7 Home computer using Node.js.

I tried using the `path` library's `path.join(...)`, but because I am on Windows, it turned all of the forward slashes backwards, which is obviously incorrect for a URL.  Example:

```
var path = require('path'),
    joined = path.join('http://www.mysite.com/', '/friends/family');

console.log(joined);
// Prints:
// http:\www.miserable.com\friends\family
```

What function or library can I use to join pieces of a URL together on Windows?  Alternatively, how can I get `path.join` to force UNIX-style separators rather than those of Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

URLs aren't filesystem paths, so nothing in `path` is applicable to your requirements. I'd suggest using `url.resolve()` if it meets your needs, or `url.format()` if not. Note that you can't simply substitute either for `path.join()` in your code, since they require different arguments. Read the documentation carefully.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I knew about the `url` module but didn't realize that `url.resolve` would join together urls.  I thought that `path` might be the next best option.

Comment: A word to the wise that url.resolve is not a drop in replacement for path.join but for URLs. Rather it "Take a base URL, and a href URL, and resolve them as a browser would for an anchor tag.". Specifically note that if you give it "http://example.com/one" and "two" it will give you "http://example.com/two" and NOT "http://example.com/one/two"

Answer (score 4):

> ...how can I get path.join to force UNIX-style separators rather than those of Windows?

While (as @ebohlman noted) URLs aren't filesystem paths, [`path.posix.join()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_windows_vs_posix) could be used to create the `URL.pathname` component.

```js
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

const origin = 'http://www.example.com/';
const pathname = path.posix.join(path.posix.sep, 'friends', 'family');

// All at once...
const myURL = new URL(pathname, origin);
console.log(myURL.href);
// => 'http://www.example.com/friends/family'

// In steps...
const myURL2 = new URL(origin);
console.log(myURL2.href);
// => 'http://www.example.com/'
myURL2.pathname = pathname;
console.log(myURL2.href);
// => 'http://www.example.com/friends/family'
```

Answer (score 2):

`url.resolve` isn't what I thought it'd be at first glance... Notice how dir1 is dropped in 2nd example

```
url.resolve('/one/two/three', 'four')         // '/one/two/four'
url.resolve('http://domain.com/dir1', 'dir2');   // 'http://domain.com/dir2  (dir1 is gone!)
```

Here's a simple join method I wrote:

```
    var _s = require('underscore.string');
    /**
     * Joins part1 and part2 with optional separator (defaults to '/'),
     * and adds the optional prefix to part1 if specified 
     * 
     * @param {string} part1
     * @param {string} part2
     * @param {string} [separator] - defaults to '/'
     * @param {string} [prefix] - defaults to empty... pass in "http://" for urls if part1 might not already have it.
     * @returns {string}
     */
    exports.joinWith = function(part1, part2, separator, prefix) {
        var join = "";
        var separatorsFound = 0;

        if( !separator) { separator = "/"; }
        if( !prefix ) { prefix = ""; }

        if( _s.endsWith( part1, separator ) ) { separatorsFound += 1; }
        if( _s.startsWith( part2, separator) ) { separatorsFound += 1; }

        // See if we need to add a join separator or remove one (if both have it already)
        if( separatorsFound === 0 ) { join = separator; }
        else if( separatorsFound === 2 ) { part1 = part1.substr(0, part1.length - separator.length ); }

        // Check if prefix is already set
        if( _s.startsWith( part1, prefix ) ) { prefix = ""; }

        return prefix + part1 + join + part2;
    }
```

Sample:

```
// TEST
console.log( exports.joinWith('../something', 'else') );
console.log( exports.joinWith('../something/', 'else') );

console.log( exports.joinWith('something', 'else', "-") );
console.log( exports.joinWith('something', 'up', "-is-") );
console.log( exports.joinWith('something-is-', 'up', "-is-") );

console.log( exports.joinWith('../something/', '/else') );
console.log( exports.joinWith('../something/', '/else', "/") );
console.log( exports.joinWith('somedomain.com', '/somepath', "/") );
console.log( exports.joinWith('somedomain.com', '/somepath', "/", "http://") );

console.log( exports.joinWith('', '/somepath', "/") );
```

OUTPUT:

```
../something/else
../something/else
something-else
something-is-up
something-is-up
../something/else
../something/else
somedomain.com/somepath
http://somedomain.com/somepath
/somepath
```